# How to remove data from Hive box without leaving null?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm trying to remove information from a Hive Box without returning null and instead reform the list with the updated indexes.

e.g

```
Data in Box ( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] )

box.deleteAt(1);

Current Outcome: ( [1,null,3,4,5,6,7] )
box.length // Outcome 8

WANTED OUTCOME:  ( [1,3,4,5,6,7] )
box.length // Outcome 7
```

How would I achieve the Wanted Outcome?

Comment: Replace `box.length` to `box.valuesBetween()` ?

Comment: @JMApps im not trying to get the length but im trying to delete the value and the list length to change as a result of the deleted entry. Having null in the list breaks what im trying to do. When i delete the previous data i want to to be gone completely.

Comment: Then you need to remove the value key `box.delete('some_key')` or `dataList.delete('itemKey')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `getAt` method to get that field

```
box.getAt(1);
```

if it is in a builder then

```
box.getAt(index)
```

By the way you can pass this value to variable.

- [referral link](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/376)

Comment: but then how would I delete this variable

Comment: It seems this is problem in Hive, but you can pass list again with new values instead of this, but getAt works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and currenty Hive doesn't have the remove method as you expect,  maybe you can filter list from box.values by this way:

```
final List<int> boxValueWithoutNull = box.values.whereType<int>().toList();
print(boxValueWithoutNull.length) // Outcome 7
```

Comment: Thank you but the fact that the list contains null is the thing which is breaking the application. I am trying to find a way to delete the information without leaving null.